# Particles disappear when no physics set

Tags: rendering, particles, physics

So I created a forest scene using hair particles system for trees and bushes. These particles stay stationary and only the camera and my character moves in the animation. So to better the render time, i read that i can turn off physics. But when i try to do that, my particles just disappear. That kind of makes sense and if there is no physics/gravity, they will just float, but disappear?

1. Physics off: [image]
2. Physics on: [image]

Comment: Did you set the start and end on frame one? Did you set the lifetime of the particles to be as long as the animation?

Comment: the frame in the timeline is from 1 to 250. Where do you set the lifetime of particles? Also, don't know if it matters, I'm using hair system.

Answer (score 1):

Hair particles are in fact trajectories of regular particles ; the regular particle need to have a motion, so it needs physics. Of course this is not a real motion, as it don't vary in time, but a path, a trajectory.

To reduce render time, you can turn off Hair Dynamics, which is the motion applied to every hair particle. It is off by default.

It's kinda weird to use hair particles to render actual objects. A regular particle system would work fine and is much easier to configure.

Comment: Most of the tutorials I read talked about using hair particle for forest creation. I will try emitter method too. SO basically people talking turning off physics to better render time does not work with hair particle system?