# Why do my hair particles disappear when physics is set to None

Tags: particles, physics, hair

As detailed in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202784/how-to-control-scale-of-hair-particles), I'm trying to create a scene with a grassy patch of dirt and I'm having trouble controlling scale and direction.

One of the bizarre relationships I discovered is that the "timestep" setting in the "Physics" tab will change the scale of the rendered particles.  So since I'm not currently using physics, I tried turning physics off by setting physics to "None".

And then all my particles simply disappeared.  They come back when I set physics back to "Newtonian".

Same problem as in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131804/particles-disappear-when-no-physics-set), but the only answer given says that physics are needed for hair (then why is there a "None" option?!) and that one should use a "regular particle system" instead of hair.  I'm not sure what a "regular particle system" is.  Are there two types of particle systems in Blender?  I know there is instancing available, but as far as I can tell I can't randomize things well using that.

Can someone explain a)  why the timestep affects the particle's scale and b)  how I avoid that interaction if I can't set physics to "None"?

Answer (score 0):

**Different particle systems:**
A "regular particle system" is of type Emitter and spawns particles which hava a size, different modes of display (object instancing etc) and move according to the selected form of physics simulation.

A Hair particle system is not identical to that, since Hair particles require a different set of information; they have a root connecting them to the emitter and are path objects, which can be physically simulated as well - this is what the **Hair Dynamics** option is for.
As long as you don't enable **Hair Dynamics**, your particles shouldn't move or collide, regardless of the selected **Physics** option.

**Hair particles require a velocity.** Tweaking it will result in a different size, which should correlate to your observation regarding timesteps: changing the speed by which time passes changes all velocities. A hair particle with a velocity of zero has a length of zero, so setting the Physics type to "None" is a bad idea; it means we are creating particles without speed and therefor without length.